# CreateConnection() fails if a huge number of requests try to use IPooledObjectPolicy simultaneously for the first time

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I need to use RabbitMQ in my .NET application. My strategy is to have a single `IConnection` and multiple `IModel` handled by `IPooledObjectPolicy`.

Problem is if a huge number of requests try to use `SendMessage` method simultaneously for the first time, I get this error message on `factory.CreateConnection();` I believe the message itself is irrelevant to the actual problem:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException
> Message=None of the specified endpoints were reachable
> IOException: connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout

If only one request tries to use `SendMessage` for the first time, everything works fine after that even if a huge number of requests triggers simultaneously.

Here is implementation of the `IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel>`:

```
private readonly RabbitMqConfigurations rabbitMqConfigurations;
private readonly IConnection _connection;

public RabbitModelPooledObjectPolicy(IOptions<RabbitMqConfigurations> RabbitMqConfigurations)
{
    rabbitMqConfigurations = RabbitMqConfigurations.Value;
    _connection = GetConnection();
}

private IConnection GetConnection()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = rabbitMqConfigurations.HostName
    };

    return factory.CreateConnection(); //<-- it fails
}

public IModel Create() => return _connection.CreateModel();

public bool Return(IModel obj)
{
    if (obj.IsOpen)
        return true;
    else
    {
        obj?.Dispose();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I used the `IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel>`:

```
private readonly DefaultObjectPool<IModel> objectPool;

public RabbitMQProducer(IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel> objectPolicy)
{
    objectPool = new DefaultObjectPool<IModel>(objectPolicy, Environment.ProcessorCount * 2);
}

public void SendMessage<T>(T message, string queue) where T : class
{
    var channel = objectPool.Get();

    try
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queue, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        properties.Persistent = true;

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: queue, basicProperties: properties, body: body);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        objectPool.Return(channel);
    }
}
```

I registered these two services as singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel>, RabbitModelPooledObjectPolicy>();
services.AddSingleton<IMessageProducer, RabbitMQProducer>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could manage to fix this.

**Explanation of the problem:**

`RabbitModelPooledObjectPolicy` constructor executes when class is accessed for the first time. While the constructor is executing, application is trying to handle other requests as well and the requests are a lot and are keep coming like a non-stop stream.

Therefore it seems somehow application is abandoning `factory.CreateConnection()` temporarily to handle other coming requests in order to executes `factory.CreateConnection()` later. However, there is no end to coming requests and the same scenario goes until `factory.CreateConnection()` throws a time out exception.

**Solution:**

I warmed up `IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel>` in `Configure` method in `startup.cs` to execute `RabbitModelPooledObjectPolicy` constructor in startup before application gets ready and receives requests.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IPooledObjectPolicy<IModel>>();
}
```